# MS.Internal.InternalMemoryStream becomes MS.Internal.ReadOnlyBufferedStream in Background Agent?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8

I am confused by something.

I have a Windows Phone 8 application that utilizes a background agent scheduled task.

Among other things, the background agent download and extracts a .zip file, using the [unzipper found here](http://www.sharpgis.net/post/2009/04/22/REALLY-small-unzip-utility-for-Silverlight.aspx). (The unzip functionality works fine in the regular, non-background parts of the application.)

I noticed that the background agent was throwing a System.NotImplementedException, and I tracked it down to a line of code within Unzipper.ParseCentralDirectory()

```
private List<FileEntry> ParseCentralDirectory()
{
    BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(this.stream);
    //this next line is the one that's throwing the System.NotImplementedException
    reader.BaseStream.Seek(-4, SeekOrigin.End);
```

In this case, "this.stream" in the BinaryReader parameter is defined at the top of the class:

```
public sealed class Unzipper : IDisposable
{
    private Stream stream;
    ...
```

As I mentioned, the unzipper functionality works fine in the regular main application.  So I looked for differences in the section of code in question between the main application and the background application (the unzipper class appears, separately, in both the main project and the background agent project.)

I noticed that the stream in Unzipper (referenced as "this.stream") is a MS.Internal.InternalMemoryStream.  However, when the background agent reaches this same line in the background Unzipper.cs, "this.stream" is a MS.Internal.ReadOnlyBufferedStream.

This is the only difference I found.  However, I am not even sure if this is the problem.  It is throwing System.NotImplementedException on

```
reader.BaseStream.Seek(-4, SeekOrigin.End);
```

but the MS.Internal.ReadOnlyBufferedStream does, in fact, have a "CanSeek" property of "true" (which I notice Unzipper checks for, and throws a NotSupportedException if it is false.)

I am stumped here.  Indeed, googling "MS.Internal.ReadOnlyBufferedStream" yields not a single result (although I'm guessing it will now...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background agents have significantly different implementations compared to their foreground counterparts for most network-based APIs.

All I can recommend is to stream the data to a temporary file in isolated storage and then open a stream to *that* file to unzip.

Keep in mind that you only have 6mb of memory (RAM) to play with, including your application assemblies, after which your task will be terminated (and unscheduled if it happens 3 times). This may lead to memory issues while unzipping.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I attempted this approach, downloading the file to isolated storage, then opening an isolatedStorageStream and passing that to a new instance of Unzipper.  This throws "System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable."

Comment: Also, could you elaborate more on how the network-based APIs differ in background agnets?  I can't seem to find any info on this.

Comment: Your first issue sounds like you're disposing the files stream before passing it to the zipping library.

Comment: As for the APIs, I'm referring to this [issue I ran into](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/94f7febb-ebc6-4611-a02b-14b51978a6e5)